# Making a script that transforms sentences to title case?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command that I use to transform sentences to title case. It is inefficient to have to copy this command out of a text file, and then paste it into the terminal before then also pasting in the sentence I want converted. The command is:

```
echo "my text" | sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g'
```

How can I convert this to a script so I can just call something like the following from the terminal:

```
TitleCaseConverter "my text"
```

Is it possible to create such a script? Is it possible to make it work from any folder location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about just wrapping it into a function in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` and `source` it from the current shell

```
TitleCaseConverter() {
    sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g' <<<"$1"    
}
```

or) if you want it pitch-perfect to avoid any sorts of trailing new lines from the input arguments do

```
printf "%s" "$1" | sed 's/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z]*/\u&/g'
```

Now you can `source` the file once from the command line to make the function available, do

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can use it in the command line directly as

```
str="my text"
newstr="$(TitleCaseConverter "$str")"
printf "%s\n" "$newstr"
My Text
```

Also to your question,

> How can I convert this to a script so I can just call something like the following from the terminal

Adding the function to one of the start-up files takes care of that, recommend adding it to `.bash_profile` more though.

```
TitleCaseConverter "this is stackoverflow"
This Is Stackoverflow
```

---

#### Update:

OP was trying to create a directory with the name returned from the function call, something like below

```
mkdir "$(TitleCaseConverter "this is stackoverflow")"
```

The key again here is to double-quote the command-substitution to avoid undergoing word-splitting by shell.

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way to now use this with mkdir? I tried using: mkdir TitleCaseConverter "this is stackoverflow". But it created two directories, one for TitleCaseConverter, and one for "this is stackoverflow".

Comment: Great, one final thing, is there a way to make it skip words like 'a', 'the', 'is', 'of', etc. So it only title cases the other words? If this requires a lot more complication then don't worry about it I will use the script you have given above as this is a very minor issue!

Comment: @eurocoder: Yup, this is a lot beyond the scope of the current question. If you really want to get a proper answer, post it as a new one! Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Since `bash`'s *parameter expansion* includes [case modification](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#case_modification), there's no need for `sed`.  Just a short function:

```
 tc() { set ${*,,} ; echo ${*^} ; }
```

Test (don't use quotes, since a title is typically no longer than a sentence, it shouldn't matter):

```
tc FOO bar
```

Output:

```
Foo Bar
```

---

Fancy version that avoids capitalizing some conjunctions, articles and such:

```
ftc() { set ${*,,} ; set ${*^} ; echo -n "$1 " ; shift 1 ; \
        for f in ${*} ; do \
            case $f in  A|The|Is|Of|And|Or|But|About|To|In|By) \
                    echo -n "${f,,} " ;; \
                 *) echo -n "$f " ;; \
            esac ; \
        done ; echo ; }
```

Test:

```
ftc the last of the mohicans
```

Output:

```
The Last of the Mohicans
```

Comment: This works great as a function, but when I have tried to convert it to a stand alone shebang script I seem to be failing on the ${,,} syntax right of the bat with a “bad substitution” error. Feel I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @lbutlr, Wrong shebang, the `bash` substitution code won't work as a *POSIX* shell script.  Supposing the script's name is *ftc.sh*, then: `sed -i '1s#/sh$#/bash#' ftc.sh` should fix it...

Comment: How can this be used in a pipe? ie: pbpaste | tc

Comment: `tc: bad substitution`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have comment privs, but slight improvement to ManUnitedBloke's answer, this will handle contractions like "don't" and "who's".

`echo "don't and who's" | sed "s/.*/\L&/; s/[a-z']*/\u&/g"`

output:
`Don't And Who's`

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is old, however after (requiring similar and )finding this post and agc's response which was great, I then desired something a somewhat more intricate that allowed for exceptions, even for the first 'word'. For the many code samples I had found, the first word was always converted Camel-case. So with some tweaks I came up with this.
There are some ridiculous exceptions in there like eBay, BBQ, KFC, McDonald's and the like, but that was more of seeing how far I could push it, and are (obviously) not required.
This **function** also removes leading & trailing spaces.
This was created with nothing other than pure bash(4.3.), no other programs needed.

I've posted my result back here in case someone else might be looking for something like this.

```
ftc() {
   ((CHR_PTR=0))
   set ${*,,}
   for f in ${*} ; do
      case $f in
         ebay) c+="eBay " ;;
         mcdonalds|"mcdonald's") c+="McDonald's " ;;
         vs) c+="vs. " ;;
         a|about|and|but|by|for|in|is|of|or|the|to) \
             [ "$CHR_PTR" -eq "0" ] && {
                c+="${f^} "
             } || {
                c+="$f "
             } ;;
         bbq|diy|hdtv|hf|kfc|mdf|sdtv|shf|tv|uhf|vlf|vhf) c+="${f^^} " ;;
         *) c+="${f^} " ;;
      esac
      ((CHR_PTR++))
   done
   x=${c## } ; c=${x%% }
   echo "$c"
}
```

Calling the function as:

```
LINEINPUT="  a diy tv and ebay didn't work for me (11 reasons why), but it's 2023 and Kfc vs mcdonald's "
FOO=$(ftc "${LINEINPUT}")
echo "$FOO"
```

Result:  A DIY TV and eBay Didn't Work for Me (11 Reasons Why), but It's 2023 and KFC vs. McDonald's